# C++ Overload Typecast to Double

Tags: c++

I'm working on an another assignment and I can't figure out how to overload a typecast to double. I need to provide the implementation. Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Here's the function prototype/declaration in my HugeInteger.h file.

```
operator double(void)const;
```

Here's a sample of code to test the overloaded type cast to double operator.

```
cout << "\n****** Test overloaded type cast to double operator ******\n";
    cout << "\nA = " << A << "\nB = " << B << "\n";
    double dA = (double)A;             // one way to invoke cast operator
    double dB = static_cast<double>(B); // another way to invoke cast operator
    cout << "\nA cast to a double is: " << dA;
    cout << "\nB cast to a double is: " << dB << '\n' << endl;
```

Comment: What part of implementing it are you stuck on? The general procedure for cast operators? The algorithm to turn your class into a `double`?

Comment: I would guess the OP is asking the syntax for providing an implementation for `operator double() const;` outside the class definition.

Comment: Hi Chris. I'm stuck on the algorithm to cast my class into a double.

Comment: Not enough information! How could we help you implement a cast operator for your class without any information about it? Give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Could be of help: [cppreference.com - user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I figured it out. This was a terrible long assignment. Was sort of brain dead near the end so my mind went blank for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct Money {
         operator double() { return _amount; }

     private:
          double _amount;
   };

   int main() {
       Money Account;
      double CashOnHand = Account;
   }
```

This is a demo in Micrsoft.It's a typecast(auto) from user's type to double. So I think it's a good way to do your work. You are not limited to the function ,you can do more in it ,or build a frame around it. I hope this is helpful.
By the way , ambiguous ！！！

Comment: Thanks Seven. You explained it very well by providing an example. I think I figured it out.